# Cannot convert 266:class java.math.BigDecimal to Long for column

Tags: postgresql, scala, heroku, playframework, anorm

I'm working with Play 2.1.1, Postgress and Herkou, and getting weird exceptions only from my production database.

Locally vs H2, everything works. On production however, the same operation fails with:

```
2013-06-14T01:49:25.275717+00:00 app[web.1]: [←[37minfo←[0m] application - 2013-06-14T01:49:25.275Z - Updating cache with new peak 266
2013-06-14T01:49:48.310600+00:00 app[web.1]: [←[37minfo←[0m] application - Updating database with peak 266
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327490+00:00 app[web.1]: [←[31merror←[0m] application -
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327490+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327490+00:00 app[web.1]: ! @6eih9flgb - Internal server error, for (GET) [/updateDB] ->
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327490+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327490+00:00 app[web.1]: play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 266:
class java.math.BigDecimal to Long for column ColumnName(peaks.price,Some(price)))]]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327490+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327490+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327490+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUp
streamHandler.scala:314) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327490+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUp
streamHandler.scala:312) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327490+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10-2.1.0.j
ar:2.1.0]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327660+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10-2.1.0.j
ar:2.1.0]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327660+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.RuntimeException: TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 266:class java.math.BigDecimal to Long for co
lumn ColumnName(peaks.price,Some(price)))
2013-06-14T01:49:48.322664+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/updateDB host=www.bitcoinpeak.org fwd="84.94.173.221" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms
 service=2019ms status=500 bytes=1941
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327660+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327660+00:00 app[web.1]:    at anorm.Sql$.as(Anorm.scala:535) ~[anorm_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327660+00:00 app[web.1]:    at anorm.Sql$class.executeInsert(Anorm.scala:474) ~[anorm_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327660+00:00 app[web.1]:    at anorm.SimpleSql.executeInsert(Anorm.scala:370) ~[anorm_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327660+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.bitcoinpeak.Peak$$anonfun$addPeak$1.apply(Peak.scala:43) ~[bitcoin-peak_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1
.0-SNAPSHOT]
2013-06-14T01:49:48.327660+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.bitcoinpeak.Peak$$anonfun$addPeak$1.apply(Peak.scala:40) ~[bitcoin-peak_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1
.0-SNAPSHOT]
2013-06-14T01:50:24.933750+00:00 app[web.1]: [←[37minfo←[0m] application - 2013-06-14T01:50:24.933Z - Updating cache with new peak 266
2013-06-14T01:51:24.796588+00:00 app[web.1]: [←[37minfo←[0m] application - 2013-06-14T01:51:24.796Z - Updating cache with new peak 266
2013-06-14T01:51:40.719105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=www.bitcoinpeak.org fwd="74.86.158.106" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms servic
e=7ms status=404 bytes=1900
2013-06-14T01:52:25.047381+00:00 app[web.1]: [←[37minfo←[0m] application - 2013-06-14T01:52:25.047Z - Updating cache with new peak 266
2013-06-14T01:52:33.646553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=www.bitcoinpeak.org fwd="74.86.158.107" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service
=21ms status=200 bytes=1892
2013-06-14T01:53:25.420489+00:00 app[web.1]: [←[37minfo←[0m] application - 2013-06-14T01:53:25.420Z - Updating cache with new peak 266
```

This is how the production table looks like:

```
> \d+ Peaks
                                         Table "public.peaks"
 Column |            Type             |       Modifiers        | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------+-----------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 price  | numeric(20,0)               | not null               | main    |              |
 time   | timestamp without time zone | not null default now() | plain   |              |
```

Why does the same code that works in local fail in production?
Is the SQL flavor? How can I fix it?

The weird part is that the transaction I'm trying to do (inserting a row) does work - the row is added. So where does the exception come from?

The entire project [is one github](https://github.com/ripper234/bitcoin-peak), if anyone needs more context.

Update: the case class:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal
import org.joda.time.DateTime

case class Peak(
  time: DateTime,
  price: BigDecimal
)
```

Comment: Can you show your case class and how you parse the row? It looks like postgresql jdbc is mapping `numeric(20,0)` to `BigDecimal` while you are expecting a `Long`.

Comment: @maba - added the case class to the question - https://github.com/ripper234/bitcoin-peak/blob/master/app/org/bitcoinpeak/Peak.scala

Comment: There is both a case class and an object named `Peak` - could this be the source of the problem?

Comment: I've seen this with sql server aswell.  I guess it's because numerics can have decimal places.  You can convert them safely to longs using the longValueExact method - it'll throw if its too big for a long or if there is a decimal part.  Frankly its a pain and I'd possibly suggest just using bigint (or whatever the equivalent is for the dbms you are using) everywhere instead of fiddly smaller precision numbers that are going to cause you trouble

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similiar issue when using different database systems. I therefore suggest that you check your database version, the configuration, the DDL of the table and the exact JDBC driver used for subtile differences that makes a column appear as BigDecimal in one case and Long in another.

You also might wanna look in this ticket: http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/243-weird-typedoesnotmatch-exception-in-rc-3-and-final

there seems to be an issue with ordering of columns and certain versions of play.

Comment: Not really a good answer, this fits more as a comment. I'm using the latest production versions ... I don't know what to check about it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but I'll reply in case other people stumble across this issue and search on SO.

It seems that in your case, the data type returned by your JDBC driver are returning a `Long` data type when using the H2 driver, and a `BigDecimal` data type with the Postgres driver. This behavior may be up to the driver implementation and how the database decides to convert its database data types into Java types using JDBC. In the H2 case, it does it with a `Long` and you're good. In the case of Postgres, it decides to return a `BigDecimal` instead.

There is a similar problem although with a different root cause described at [this link](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/346-anorm-doesnt-properly-convert-biginteger-to-long). There is a provided solution that should work for you using implicit conversion of `Column[BigInt]` into `Column[Long]`, but instead we'll convert from `Column[BigDecimal]` into `Column[Long]`:

```scala
implicit def rowToLong: Column[Long] = Column.nonNull { (value, meta) =>
  val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
    value match {
      case int: Int => Right(int: Long)
      case long: Long => Right(long)
      case bd:BigDecimal => Right(bd.longValue())  //Handle BigDecimal correctly
      case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + ":" + value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass + " to Long for column " + qualified))
    }
}
```

This should convert to the `Long` type any `BigDecimal`, `Long` or `int`. This is almost identical to the original Scala code in the Anorm `Column` class except for the addition of the the `BigDecimal` handling!

There is also some more evolved implicit conversion in [this (refused) pull request](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/204/files). It's good to note that these changes are refused because the behavior of these extra implicit conversions would be uncertain, considering that the fixes depend on which JDBC driver is being used and possibly which version. Most important too, this is *magic behavior* that modifies the data. Hence the user should be the one responsible for these changes, unfortunately. Apply this fix with care and make sure it interacts well with all your environments and the **data**.

Answer (score 0):

Create an AnormExtension helper in app/helpers folder.  Call it AnormExtension.scala.  Code below.  Also, it's probably better to convert a BigDecimal to Double instead of Long.

FYI - Notice that I don't try to convert to Scala BigDecimal.  Scala BigDecimal is a mystery.  I would leave it alone.

```
object AnormExtension {

 implicit def rowToDouble: Column[Double] = Column.nonNull { (value, meta) =>
   val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
     value match {
       case d: java.math.BigDecimal => Right(d.doubleValue())
       case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + ":" + value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass + " to Double for column " + qualified))
     }
 }
}
```